# Counting intersections per run of 1s in the first of two logical vectors

Tags: r, range, intersection, interval-intersection

A more general version of this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395292/intersecting-ranges-of-consecutive-values-in-logical-vectors-in-r). A user proposed I ask this more specific version of the question as a separate post.

I have two logical vectors which look like this:

```
x = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
y = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I want to count the intersections between ranges of consecutive values (in this example 1111) in such a way, that at most one intersection per run of 1s in the first vector is counted.

Using `sum(rle(x & y)$values)` from the above mentioned answer, I can count the total number of intersections of the above vectors as *two*, but I expect *one*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want max length of the intersection to be 1. If so, you can do

```
sum(with(rle(x & y), lengths == 1 & values))
#[1] 1
```

When we do `x & y` the numeric values of `x` and `y` are changed to logical values where 1 is represented as `TRUE` and `FALSE` as 0. Since we are only interested in intersection of 1's (i.e `TRUE`) with at most 1 intersection we count the number of times where this condition is satisfied i.e `lengths == 1` (or `lengths <= 1` as we need to check for at most) and `values` meaning only 1's i.e `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

We can also write it as

```
sum(with(rle(x & y), lengths * values) == 1)
#[1] 1
```